# What do you call a word that substitutes an obscene word?

Tags: euphemisms

A word that is milder than another is a euphemism, but what is a generic word that is used in good manners and polite speech instead of the proper specific term, like 'bottom' instead of 'ass'?

Comment: Those are euphemisms, too. The whole point is that they're not bad words that will harm you magically; as such, they can be used in polite company. There are grades of euphemism, though. The taint is not so easy to wash off, and styles change. As soon as the strategy is detected, it becomes less effective, and new euphemisms replace old. It's good for the advertising industry.

Comment: @John Lawler Sounds appropriate for the panto season. _New euphemisms for old._

Comment: But _ass_ isn't the 'proper, specific term' for the buttocks. I would have said that _bottom_ was a fairly standard term, for which there are many euphemisms (_sit-upon, backside, derriere_ and so on).